# Solving a problem using energy conservation doesn't work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

Hello I'm trying to solve the following problem as I'm preparing for physics olympiads:

[image]

The solution they gave involves finding the forces acting on the cylinder and hence finding acceleration, which allows us to figure out distance and time. However, I tried to find the distance it takes to stop using energy conservation and it doesn't give the same answer as the book solution.
My energy conservation equation is:

Kinetic energy of block + kinetic energy of disk + rational kinetic energy of disk = work done by friction acting on block

Since the friction force acting on the disk is static, it does no work. No other forces do any work, so doesn't all the kinetic energy of the system turn into work done by kinetic friction on block?

What's wrong with my approach here?

Comment: Let me know if I should post the book solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've missed something major, I did get the same answer with both approaches

The energy method however is more complex than it seems, and does required finding at least one force, tension in the string. This is because limiting frictional force in classical mechanics is taken as directly proportional to normal reaction between the surfaces considered.

A component of tension changes this normal reaction, meaning you cannot find the frictional force acting on your block unless you have already found tension. Just as a quick gut check, the angle the string makes with the horizontal is 30 degrees, a standard angle.

Comment: Yeah I took normal force as just weight. Thanks a lot!